# PC's and Laptops get IP from DHCP, but other devices don't?

Tags: networking, dhcp

We're having a strange issue. DHCP is setup on a Windows 2013 Server PC, it works fine for laptops and computers, even VoIP phones.

But not for our access point (or devices connecting VIA the access point), or a printer.

I've tried this on another network here in the office and the devices get IP's just fine. I've also tried connecting the devices directly to the first Switch in the chain.

What could be causing this?

Comment: You will have to tell us a lot more about your AP configuration before anyone can hope to help.

Comment: IT's not an isolated issue to the AP. A Sharp network printer is getting the same issue. The AP is a WAP54G with latest firmware. It does nothing more than be an access point. IP address for the AP is static and is correct. Wireless devices connecting to the AP don't receive IP's from DHCP. If the AP itself is set to dynamic IP, that too doens't get an IP address. It works fine on a separate network here owned by another company.

Comment: Where you get Windows 2013 Server? :)  Anyhow, are you sure the DHCP server service has enough IP's remaining in the pool?

Comment: Is the AP static IP outside the DHCP pool range? Perhaps you've got a clash? Do you have any clashing MAC addresses (slim chance?)?

Comment: @BigChris Server 2012 sorry! Yes the DHCP range _should be_ 100+ devices, we have 3 PC's, 3 VOIP phones and a number of servers. The staticly asigned IP's are all outside of the range... Although I should check the range is correct... I'll keep this updated as it's being a pain!

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Should also mention that we have CISCO firewall that was newly set up here, and a VPN connection to a network on Microsoft Azure. Although that all seems to be fine. Cisco firewall has DHCP disabled.